# calculate Euclidean Distance for three means

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm having trouble doing the calculations for Euclidean Distance.

Later on I refer to the function and it gives me this error:

TypeError: ufunc 'bitwise_and' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

It is needed for a hardcoded K-means algorithm.

```
def euclideanDist(df,pointIDX,mean_1,mean_2,mean_3):

    point = df.iloc[pointIDX][['Shoe_Size','Height']].values
    mean_1 = mean_1[['Shoe_Size','Height']].values
    mean_2 = mean_2[['Shoe_Size','Height']].values
    mean_3 = mean_3[['Shoe_Size','Height']].values

    dist_Total_1 = sum([a-b for a,b in zip(point,mean_1)])**2
    dist_Total_2 = sum([a-b for a,b in zip(point,mean_2)])**2
    dist_Total_3 = sum([a-b for a,b in zip(point,mean_3)])**2

    if dist_Total_1 < dist_Total_2 & dist_Total_3: 
        df.loc[pointIDX,'class'] = 1

    elif dist_Total_2 < dist_Total_3 > dist_Total_1:
        df.loc[pointIDX, "class"] = 2

    else:
        df.loc[pointIDX,'class'] = 3

    return df
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have some syntax problems here

```
if dist_Total_1 < dist_Total_2 & dist_Total_3: 
    df.loc[pointIDX,'class'] = 1

elif dist_Total_2 < dist_Total_3 > dist_Total_1:
    df.loc[pointIDX, "class"] = 2
```

I believe what you really want is

```
if dist_Total_1 < dist_Total_2 and dist_Total_1 < dist_Total_3: 
    df.loc[pointIDX,'class'] = 1

elif dist_Total_2 < dist_Total_3 and dist_Total_2 < dist_Total_1:
    df.loc[pointIDX, "class"] = 2
```

Your distance calculation also does not appear to fit with my understanding of euclidean distance. Perhaps this instead

```
dist_Total_1 = sum([(a-b)**2 for a,b in zip(point,mean_1)])**0.5
```

and so on with `dist_Total_2` and `dist_Total_3`.

Comment: So the math behind was right, and it was just a syntax error?

Comment: From what I remember of euclidean distance, you want to square each individual subtraction and then take the square root of the sum of those terms.

Comment: I have added a sample distance measure in my answer that is in line with my thinking.

Comment: I know there's an error somewhere because the output of my k-means doesn't class any of the points. They all go directly to class 1.

Comment: Check out my edit to my answer and please see if it helps and let me know.

Comment: Can you tell me in words what each `if` and `elif` is trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to cluster my data into 3 clusters, meaning I would need 3 centroids (means).

Comment: I made an edit to the `elif`. Namely, `elif dist_Total_2 < dist_Total_3 and dist_Total_2 < dist_Total_1:`. From what I remember of K-means clustering, this is what you truly want instead.

Comment: Also there's a last, else statement meaning, if neither of above is true, throw it into class 3. This should give me in total 3 (almost) even clusters

Comment: Right. It looks like you had that fine in there already, so I left it alone. I would not change your `else` statement.

Comment: In regards to the mathy part, shouldn't the second part of elif be, dist_Total_2 > dist_Total_1. Total 2 would be in between the other two, so it should be larger than 1 and less than dist_Total_3, correct?

Comment: To be in the second class, a point would need to be less distance from the mean of the 2nd class than it is from the means of both the 1st and 3rd class.